# ¿Por qué no encuentra mi controlador Laravel?

Tags: laravel, controller

En mi proyecto tengo un Controlador el cual se llama `UsuarioController` pero por error cambie el nombre a `aaUsuarioController`, cuando me di cuanta volvi a cambiar el nombre a **UsuarioController** , pero ahora laravel me busca el controlador **aaUsuarioController** en lugar de buscar **UsuarioController** y no sé como solucionar ese error

esto es lo que me sale

> include(C:\Users\neide\code\CRUD\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/aaUsuarioController.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinicia el autoload con `composer dump-autoload`, así actualizas las clases del cargador automático de clases.

Comment: listo ya lo hice y me funciono , ahora una pregunta solo me actualizas las clases del cargador automático de clases , o hace algo mas , quiero decir resetea o actualiza algo mas?

Comment: Simplemente regenera la lista de todas las clases que deben incluirse en el proyecto (autoload_classmap.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Me está pasando lo mismo ahora, pero en mi caso la respuesta que te dieron no me ha funcionado. He creado el login por defecto de laravel (que crea User.php model). Así que, manualmente he creado UsuarioController, todas las rutas hacia ese controlador y me dice que el controlador "Usuario" no se encuentra. No entiendo nada. En ningún momento hago referencia a "Usuario", siempre a "UsuarioController"